# Meaning of "l" in "lrwxr-xr-x"?

Tags: bash, osx, ls

According to this website:

> http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html

The first letter indicates the file type: `f` means file and `d` means directory. But in my case I've an `l`. What's the meaning of this `l`? In my case, the file is actually a directory too.

Also some entries do not have any file type, i.e. they have a leading dash `-`. Does this mean that the OS does not recognise the file type?

Answer (score 7):

A symbolic link. Means it's a pointer to another file.

You can see the full list of file types [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types).

Comment: can someone with sufficient acces rights mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

a leading dash **'-'** means its a file.

a lead **'d'** means its a directory

a leading **'l'** means its a link to another file.

The first character identifies the file type:

- :  Regular file

b   : Block special file

c   : Character special file

d   : Directory

l   : Symbolic link

n   : Network file

p   : FIFO

s   : Socket

Comment: `-` is used to indicate a file, the ss64 page is wrongly referring to `f` which is not used, at least under Unix and Linux.

Comment: I agree with @jlliagre .Its wrongly written on the page.